# SudzC iOS auto encodes XML?

Tags: ios, sudzc

I am using SudzC for SOAP web services in an iOS App. The issue I'm facing is, there's a method which is auto generated, and whose parameters contains a simple XML payload. When i send the XML payload as a NSString to the parameter, it automatically converts the & in the XML payload to & amp;

I'm not using any encoding manually in this process. How do I avoid this? Any help would be appreciated.

Edit -
This is the part of code which is auto generated and handling by request

```
if(postData != nil) {
    [request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
    [request addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];        
    [request setHTTPBody: [postData dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    if(self.logging) {
        NSLog(@"%@", postData);
    }
}
```

Thanks

Nithin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the simple answer is you have to explore the code which has been generated by SudzC. However the hint is, When you request or receive response SudzC code is probably sanitising your code somewhere, most probably method name with serializeElement. If it is a XML request then try to jump to  several definition starting from your main method and unto Soap Create method(Just a guess, I am not sure how your code works.) Try to find code similar to this and modify it accordingly.

```
[[self.YourXML stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"&quot;"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&" withString:@"&amp;"]];
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Added the piece of code in the question.

Comment: That will not help us Nithin, Digg in, you will find it somewhere. and btw is the web service your implementation or third party? If yours then it's good to send xml by replacing those char and handle logic inside the web service to convert them from &amp; to &